# systemd: use variables in a unit file

Tags: variables, configuration, systemd

I have unit files for bunch of services. In ExecStart I want to refer to directory part of a path name using a variable so that I can easily update many unit files in case a location of executables changes.

I am using EnvironmentFile to define the variables and source the file inside a unit file. However it appears that variables are not visible inside a unit file itself but only in the environment (I haven't tested it to see if they are indeed visible in the environment). Is there any other, idomatic way to use variable for dynamic configuration?

#### EnvironmentFile

```
[Service]
Environment=MYS_PATH=/opt/myservice
Environment=MYS_USER=user
```

#### Unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
After=network.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d/myservice_defs.conf
Type=simple
User=${MYS_USER}
WorkingDirectory=${MYS_PATH}
ExecStart=${MYS_PATH}/usr/bin/myservice -C ${MYS_PATH}/etc/myservice.conf
```

Comment: My solution could cover and solve this problem here too:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/574651/401828

Comment: @sausix: your URL results in a "This question was voluntarily removed by its author." error page. (Though _I am curious_ to know what was contained in it!)

Comment: @roens The question has been deleted. I still can see my answer privately when logged in. The first argument (the executable) can't be taken from environment variables. So just shift it. "bash -c ..." is too complicated cmopared to just prefix env:  ```ExecStart=/usr/bin/env ${PYTHON3} ${MY_SCRIPT}```

Comment: @sausix Ah yes, of course. Thanks for the reply! In my use, I ended up just stuffing the complexity into a shell script, then calling that (actually) in `ExecStartPre`. My `systemd` service sets up a Docker container (with specified network), then attach to that container for control with `ExecStart` & `ExecStop`. The prescribed network is necessary because the app in the container is a MySQL client where the IP it connects from is part of auth.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is "That is not how you use a EnvironmentFile", a `EnvironmentFile` should be in the form of just key value (without the Enviroment) prefix.

```
MYS_PATH=/opt/myservice
MYS_USER=user
```

what you where describing was a service overwrite and that is another thing all together, sadly your environmental variables only works on the context of the service you are launching and not the systemd unit itself. you still can use them for the Excec start except for defining the path to the binary).

But there some ways to achive what you want.

### pystemd.run or systemd-run

You can create transient units, that do not survive restarts on your system, but can be programatically defined or on the fly, my favorite (for obvious reasons) is pystemd.run but you can use systemd-run also, the first one is a python library and the second one is a cli-tool

pystemd.run

```
# install pystemd
[root@~] pip install pystemd
[root@~] python
>>> import pystemd.run
>>> MYS_PATH='/opt/myservice'
>>> MYS_USER='user'
>>> pystemd.run([f'{MYS_PATH}/usr/bin/myservice', '-C' f'{MYS_PATH}/etc/myservice.conf'], cwd=MYS_PATH, user=MYS_USER)
```

and you can do all sort of stuff because you are in python world.

systemd-run

```
[root@~] MYS_PATH='/opt/myservice'
[root@~] MYS_USER='user'
[root@~] systemd-run --uid ${MYS_USER} -p WorkingDirectory=${MYS_PATH} ${MYS_PATH}/usr/bin/myservice -C ${MYS_PATH}/etc/myservice.conf
```

### Using templates

also if you can avoid having multiple configurations you can always set template units, you just rename your unit from `myservice.service` to `myservice@.service`. Then every time you start a unit you do it like `systemctl start myservice@configsetting.service`

then on your unit you can use **configsetting** as %i anywhere you want, like this

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/myservice -C /etc/myservice/%i.conf
```

if you ask me... go with pystemd.run or systemd-run